# Azure load balancer I can't select the target virtual machine

Tags: azure, azure-load-balancer

I'm learning Azure and I'm trying to connect a load balancer to the virtual machine instances I have created that are using the same resource group and within the same availability set but the target virtual machine options within the dialog are not available.  Am I missing something perhaps?  This is a free trial account.

Is there something I've missed perhaps?

Many thanks,

[image: options are disabled]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic VMs are not eligible for load balancing. You need to use Standard VMs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes-previous-gen#basic-a

Comment: not much to try. i even gave you official docs link that says what I am saying

Comment: Yes thank you - it's more whether it resolves my personal experience and allows me to target target the vm